# How to calculate Amount based on formula in table grid using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

am calculating employee salary details , basic has default amount and remaing hr,ta  etc calculating based on Basic  value using formula
i have tried follwing
am splitting formula and passing values

html

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Sno</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Formula</th>
      <th>Total value</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="e in Employees">
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td>{{e.Name}}</td>
      <td>{{e.Amount}}</td>
      <td>{{e.Formula}}</td>
      <td>{{e.TotalValue}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

angular

```
$scope.EmployeeData = [{ Id: 1, Name: 'Basic', Amount: 100, Formula: '', TotalValue: 0 }, { Id: 2, Name: 'HR', Amount: 0, Formula: '<Basic>*10/100', TotalValue: 0 },
    { Id: 3, Name: 'TA', Amount: 0, Formula: '<Basic>+500', TotalValue: 0 }]

$scope.Employees = [];
var data = $scope.EmployeeData;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].Formula !== "") {
        $scope.Matches = data[i].Formula.replace("<", "").replace(">", ",").replace("+", "+,").replace("*", "*,").replace("-", "-,").split(',');
        $scope.Item1 = $scope.Matches[0];
        $scope.arithmeticOperator = $scope.Matches[1];
        $scope.Item2 = $scope.Matches[2];
        if ($scope.Item1 == 'Basic') {
            if ($scope.arithmeticOperator == '*') {
                data[i].TotalValue = (($scope.Value) * (eval($scope.Item2)));
            }
            else if ($scope.arithmeticOperator == '+') {
                data[i].TotalValue = (($scope.Value) + (eval($scope.Item2)));
            }
            else if ($scope.arithmeticOperator == '/') {
                data[i].TotalValue = (($scope.Value) / (eval($scope.Item2)));

            }
            else if ($scope.arithmeticOperator == '-') {
                data[i].TotalValue = (($scope.Value) - (eval($scope.Item2)));

            }
        }
//...
//like basic am given conditions for HR,TA 
    }
    else {
        $scope.Value = data[i].Amount;
    }

    //pushing data in table
    $scope.Employees.push(data[i]);
}
```

able to calculate Total value by using this ,
but is this correct way to calculate formula , 
how can i calculate Total value if  formulas like `<Basic>+100+<HR>, <Basic>+<HR>+<TA>`,
how  to calculate formula on arithmatic expression 
my code will limited to only this expression `"<basic>*100"`